# Calculating the highest of overlapping sets

Tags: distributions, mean, descriptive-statistics, median

My data set looks like the following:

> I have information about a large number of devices. For each device, I also have the data consumed by an application per day. Note however, all the devices may not have all the same applications. For instance, application A may be in use in only 70% of the devices.

I'm trying to answer the following question:

> How can we rank the applications in decreasing data usage order?

What would be the best way to do this?

EDIT:

Dev 1: Facebook 10MB, Google+ 50MB, Whatsapp 10MB
Dev 2: Facebook 2MB, Twitter 3MB, Angry Birds 50MB
..
..
Dev n: Drive 1MB, Gmail 3MB

Comment: Can you show an example of what the data look like?

Comment: I edited the main question

Comment: "Which application consumes the most data?" Are you looking for the global answer? Eg. Facebook consumes 13,35TB. Or the average for that application on one device?

Comment: Good point. See edit.